# Dark streaks appearing only when rendering image/animation (solved)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image: Rendered view of the table]

The light source is directly above the table with no objects casting a shadow. Alpha is at 1. The table is one object with no breaks. The streaks appear above the table legs. Rendered in Cycles. The closer to the light source the stronger the streaks appear.

Comment: hard to say... dark seams seem to be evenly spaced in the picture... but could you share the blend file for a closer look?

Comment: I'm so new but after a bit more exploring I found out it was objects I had hidden from the viewport but were showing up in the render.